# how to check if an environment variable exists in CircleCI?

Tags: circleci

I created an environment variable which is in this format STAGE_${CIRCLE_USERNAME}. So for my case the environment variable is STAGE_bernard. I am trying to check if the environment variable exists but my logic does not seem to be working.

This is the config.yml :

```
jobs:
  build:
    parameters:
      stage:
        type: string
        default: ""
    executor: aws-cli/default
    steps:
      - aws-cli/setup
      - checkout
      - run: 
          command: |
            if [[ -z "STAGE_${CIRCLE_USERNAME}" ]]; then
               echo "Hi"
            else
              echo "Bie"
            fi
            echo $stage
```

But when i run it, the output is Bie. But it should be Hi since the environment variable does exist. Can someone please point out what i’m doing wrong. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `if` condition is invalid. The `-z` conditional expression returns true if the length of a string is zero. `"STAGE_${CIRCLE_USERNAME}"` is a literal string that will always be at least 6 characters long ("STAGE_"), so the expression will always be false.

You can use [indirect variable reference](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/ivr.html) to make it work:

```
stage="STAGE_${CIRCLE_USERNAME}"
if [[ -n ${!stage} ]]; then
   echo "var is set"
else
  echo "var is unset"
fi
```

Notice the use of `-n` instead of `-z`. Opposite to `-z`, `-n` conditional expression returns true if the length of a string is non-zero, i.e. env var is set.

Alternatively, you can use the `-v` condition if the Bash version in your pipeline is 4.2 or higher:

```
if [[ -v "STAGE_${CIRCLE_USERNAME}" ]]; then
   echo "var is set"
else
  echo "var is unset"
fi
```